# I want to place magento order using custom script using order Management interface but it's give error of invalid email format

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I want to place magento order using custom script using order Management interface but it's give error of invalid email format.

```
`<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\PaymentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Address as OrderAddressResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Payment as OrderPaymentResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item as OrderItemResource;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Set your data here
$customerId = 1;
$store = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class)->getStore();
$currencyCode = 'USD';

// Sample product data
$productId = 1;
$productQty = 2;
$productPrice = 50.00;

// Sample shipping and billing address data
$shippingAddressData = [
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe',
    'street' => '123 Shipping Street',
    'city' => 'New York',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region' => 'NY',
    'postcode' => '10001',
    'telephone' => '1234567890',
];

$billingAddressData = [
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe',
    'street' => '456 Billing Street',
    'city' => 'New York',
    'country_id' => 'US',
    'region' => 'NY',
    'postcode' => '10001',
    'telephone' => '9876543210',
];

try {
    // Create order
    /** @var State $state */
    $state = $objectManager->get(State::class);
    $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);

    /** @var OrderInterface $order */
    $order = $objectManager->create(OrderInterface::class);
    $order->setCustomerId($customerId);
    $order->setStoreId($store->getId());
    $order->setCurrencyCode($currencyCode);

    // Add products to the order
    /** @var OrderItemInterface $orderItem */
    $orderItem = $objectManager->create(OrderItemInterface::class);
    $orderItem->setProductId($productId);
    $orderItem->setQtyOrdered($productQty);
    $orderItem->setPrice($productPrice);
    $orderItem->setBasePrice($productPrice);
    $orderItem->setRowTotal($productPrice * $productQty);
    $order->setItems([$orderItem]);

    // Validate the email format
    function isValidEmail($email)
    {
        return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    }

    $shippingEmail = 'john@example.com'; // Replace with your email address
    $billingEmail = 'jane@example.com'; // Replace with your email address

    // Set shipping address
    /** @var OrderAddressInterface $shippingAddress */
    $shippingAddress = $objectManager->create(OrderAddressInterface::class);
    $shippingAddressData['email'] = $shippingEmail;
    $shippingAddress->setData($shippingAddressData);
    $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);

    // Set billing address
    /** @var OrderAddressInterface $billingAddress */
    $billingAddress = $objectManager->create(OrderAddressInterface::class);
    $billingAddressData['email'] = $billingEmail;
    $billingAddress->setData($billingAddressData);
    $order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

    // Set payment information
    /** @var OrderPaymentInterface $payment */
    $payment = $objectManager->create(OrderPaymentInterface::class);
    $payment->setMethod('checkmo');
    $order->setPayment($payment);

    // Save order
    $orderManagement = $objectManager->get(OrderManagementInterface::class);
    try {
        $orderManagement->place($order);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error :" . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }

    // Get the increment ID of the placed order
    $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
    echo "Order placed successfully. Increment ID: " . $incrementId . " Order ID: " . $order->getId() .PHP_EOL;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}`
```

`Error: We can't save the address: Email has a wrong format`

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering an error indicating an invalid email format while trying to place a Magento order using a custom script through the Order Management interface, it typically means that the email address you are providing does not adhere to the expected format. To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the email address you provide is in a valid format.

Here are a few steps you can take to address the error:

Validate Email Format: Double-check the email address you are using and ensure that it follows the correct email format. An email address should typically have the format username@example.com, where username is a combination of alphanumeric characters and special characters like dots (.), underscores (_), or hyphens (-), and example.com represents the domain name.

Remove Leading or Trailing Spaces: Make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in the email address string. Spaces at the beginning or end can cause the email validation to fail.

Use a Valid Email Address: Confirm that the email address you are using is a valid, existing email address. You can try using a known valid email address for testing purposes to check if the error persists. Additionally, verify that the email address you are using is not already associated with an existing customer account in Magento, as it may cause conflicts during the order placement process.

Check Order Management Interface Configuration: Review the configuration of your custom script and the Order Management interface to ensure there are no specific email validation rules or restrictions imposed by your Magento instance or any customizations made to the system.

Use Magento's Email Validation Function: Consider utilizing Magento's built-in email validation function to validate the email address before attempting to place the order. You can use the Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress class to validate the email format using the isValid() method.

Example (PHP):

```
use Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress;

$email = 'user@example.com';
$validator = new EmailAddress();

if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
    // Proceed with order placement
} else {
    // Handle the invalid email format error
}
```

By validating the email address format and ensuring it meets the required criteria, you should be able to resolve the "invalid email format" error and successfully place the order using the custom script through the Order Management interface.